# JWTSecurityTokenHandler and SecurityTokenDescriptor not found even though System.IdentityModel.Tokens installed and used

Tags: c#, .net, nuget, jwt

I am trying to write a method to generate JWT token in .net C#. Searching through internet I found pages demonstrating how do do this. One such page I am following is https://gist.github.com/pmhsfelix/4151369. To support this, I ran "`Install-Package System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt`" in the package manager console and can see "`<package id="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" version="4.0.2.205111437" targetFramework="net45" />"` in my paackages.config. But still, the SecurityTokenDescriptor is not found. I have a strong feeling it is some version mismatch but I am not able to find out what is it. Can some one help me fix this?

Answer (score 11):

Make sure that in your code you use:

```
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens;
using Microsoft.IdentityModel;
```

Also, I believe you will need to add a reference to:

**System.IdentityModel**

which is found in the Assemblies tab in Visual Studio.

Hope this helps you.

Comment: `using System.IdentityModel.Tokens;` + Adding a reference to `System.IdentityModel` should do it

Comment: ^ Just adding `System.IdentityModel` does the trick. No need for `Microsoft.IdentityModel`

Answer (score 5):

After upgrading from 4.x.x to 5.x.x

Change this line:

```
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens;
```

To:

```
using System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt;
```