# JwtSecurityTokenHandler.cs Not Found

Tags: c#, visual-studio, nuget

Application errors out on trying to run this code (at least I assume, because just before is where my last breakpoint is hit):

```
app.UseJwtBearerAuthentication(
                new JwtBearerAuthenticationOptions
```

I then get the following error:

> JwtSecurityTokenHandler.cs not found

The exception is (which scares me, because it seems like it's trying to parse the token, though the error above implies the library is missing):

> {"IDX10503: Signature validation failed. Keys tried:
>   'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.InMemorySymmetricSecurityKey\r\n'.\nExceptions
>   caught:\n ''.\ntoken:
>   '{\"typ\":\"JWT\",\"alg\":\"HS256\"}.{\"iss\":\"https://something.com/\",\"sub\":\"auth0|xxxxxxx\",\"aud\":\"xxxxxxx\",\"exp\":xxxxxxx,\"iat\":xxxxxxx}'"}

The funny thing is that the code seems to work for everyone else on the team. I have deleted the Solution completely and then pulled hard from github. The problem persists. I have tried deleting and reinstalling the package - to no avail (of course, VS also reinstalled the nuget packages after the hard pull). The funny thing is that I am 99% sure I haven't touched anything package related when this started happening. I have 3 questions:

1. Given the error, can I assume that not finding the package is THE problem with 99% certainty? (If the answer is no, that might be all I need, since I am almost certain the package is the issue atm).
2. This file doesn't actually exist, right? It gets unpackaged as the solution runs from the dll?(I don't need the answer to this if we can get an answer to 3)
3. How do i fix it?

Yes, I do have all the correct references as per the [question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30358284/jwtsecuritytokenhandler-and-securitytokendescriptor-not-found-even-though-system). I have also read another question on here which I can't find right now (about messed up nuget references) - it recommended closing and opening visual studio, cleaning the solution, deleting temp files, and other similar things, all of which I tried.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has nothing to do with a missing source file (this is actually because of the fact that the exception is part of an internal microsoft library). The actual error message is IDX10503 - Signature validation failed.

To acutally trace down the problem, please refer to the aswers related to [IDX10503](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=IDX10503). Those should help.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply, looking at that now. Will come back to accept the answer if that fixes it.

Comment: On the same note - under what circumstances would I be the only one having the problem, as opposed to the whole team?

Comment: MIght be a setting problem in IIS/IISExpress (aka machine code different, not set), different locale setting in client/server, ... I've hat this problem once related to missing machine code setting in a scalable environment, but that's only one reason. You know, it's Microsoft ;)

Comment: Looks like I am in for some fun.

Comment: Stephen, thanks for the help - if you didn't answer, I would have spent another several hours (at least) trying to "fix" Nuget packages. Ended up being a ridiculous issue with the tokens themselves.